# C++ DLL Manifest error

Tags: visual-c++, dll, manifest

When I try to compile my c++ dll I get this error

> mt.exe : command line error c10100a9: Some operation on the input manifests must be specified (even if it is just to pipe the input to the output).  Use the /? option for help on usage and samples.

I have disabled Manifest Tool from the properties menu, the only reason I did that was because it was giving me a hard time to compile.
Now I can build my DLL, but only once every three times, because of the above mentioned error.
Any help to get rid of this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this q is languishing.  Is the problem you have now better or worse than what you had before disabling Manifest Tool?  Perhaps it would be worth re-enabling it and trying to work through those problems.

I have never seen this error, though I know MT.EXE has had a few problems.  Make sure you have the latest SP for your VS installation as well.

Comment: I had to enable Manifest Tool again and now all of a sudden everything works just great.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution by (*project properties ->Configuration properties ->Manifest Tool ->Input and Output*) in *Output Manifest File* type:

```
$(IntDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).embed.manifest
```

and press Ok.